# Theoretical doubt about lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

while solving some exercises related to finding maximums and minimums of functions with two variables under constraints, I encountered a doubt when using Lagrange multipliers.

For instance, considering the function ( f(x,y,z) = xyz restricted at x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 = 6 ), I found the following system:

\begin{align*}
yz &= \lambda 2x \\
xz &= \lambda 4y \\
xy &= \lambda 6z \\
\end{align*}

Subsequently, I obtained x = sqrt(2), y = + or - 1, and z = + or - sqrt(2/3).

I know that if I take the point (sqrt(2), 1, sqrt(2/3)), which is given in the answer key, it satisfies the constraint equation and seems to be a maximum point (value 2/sqrt(3)). However, this point, when substituted into xy = λ6z, does not satisfy the equality.

Hence, my question is: shouldn't a point that indeed represents an extreme under the function and constraint conditions satisfy both equations?

Comment: Oh sorry! xyz is the expression to be considered and x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 = 6 the restriction.

Comment: It does satisfy the equality. The value of $\lambda$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$ in this case (and - that in others)

Comment: I just realized this. I had calculated λ wrong. Furthermore, it seems that λ can have more than one value and, in similar questions like these, it is not necessary to discover all the critical points that lead to the extremes. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to find any of the $\lambda$ values to find the critical points (though it may be necessary as part of the computation and often is). They have meaning in some contexts